# Will the Factory Pattern solve my problem?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a requirement to create some objects that implement a given interface, where the type of concrete implementation being created is based on an Enum value.

I run into trouble when the different concrete implementations require different parameters at runtime.

This example (C#) is fine:

```
public enum ProductCategory
{
    Modem,
    Keyboard,
    Monitor
}

public class SerialNumberValidatorFactory()
{
    public ISerialNumberValidator CreateValidator(ProductCategory productCategory)
    {
        switch (productCategory)
        {
            case ProductCategory.Modem:
                return new ModemSerialNumberValidator();
            case ProductCategory.Keyboard:
                return new KeyboardSerialNumberValidator();
            case ProductCategory.Monitor:
                return new MonitorSerialNumberValidator();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("productType", string.Format("Product category not supported for serial number validation: {0}", productCategory))
        }
    }
}
```

However, what happens if the concrete implementations have different constructor arguments?  I can't pass in all the values to the `SerialNumberValidatorFactory.CreateValidator()` method, so how do I proceed?

I've heard the `Abstract Factory` pattern is supposed to solve this, but I'm not sure how to implement it properly.

Comment: Can you instead aggregate out the constructor parameters into an initialization method on the interface? This will leave you with a parameterless constructor.  Defining constructor parameters will mean the caller has to supply the arguments (unless the factory can supply them), breaking the point in using an interface as the caller is now supplying stuff specific to an implementation.

Comment: @Adam yes I'd thought about that.  Only thing is then policing the call to `Initialise()`.  At least with ctor args, they are *required* values that you can't avoid passing in.

Comment: You can always add one more layer of interfaces - a `Settings` class that contains the arguments for a given type. You can then expose an `ISettings` for each validator that asks for the settings and pass this to the class factory `CreateValidator`. This then means that you are passing typed values to another interface - so I suppose you are tied to that interface, but even passing the `ProductType` your code is already expecting a certain type, so passing a certain interface isn't going to hurt any more.

Comment: @Adam okay I'll look at that.  It's worth pointing out that ProductType is an `Enum` rather than a `Type`.

Comment: @Neil yes sorry, I was more trying to say that the code logic is already asking for a certain validator, so having it supply a validator-specific settings container is not going to morph the dependencies too much (if at all).

Comment: The calling code doesn't know which one it's asking for - it's passing a runtime value in from the user (ProductCategory).  I see your point about having a settings factory, but that would fall foul of the exact same problem I'm having here.  I think maybe the factory pattern is totally not appropriate here, and I need to find out what is the best pattern for this job.

Comment: It depends, where do the constructor arguments come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create a Settings container to pass to the `CreateValidator` method.  Start with a base `IValidatorSettings`, then create `IModemSerialNumberValidatorSettings` etc, your `CreateValidator` could then take `ProductType` and `IValidatorSettings` arguments.

Your concrete classes for the validators would then take their `IXXXValidatorSettings` interface as the sole constructor argument.

Further to this you could then create an `IValidatorSettings` factory.

I think abstract factory is a factory that creates a factory to handle a given set of types - not sure if it would apply in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

What you are using is a Factory Method pattern, what you should use is an Abstract Factory

In abstract factory, you provide a factory class for each concrete implementation:

So your code becomes: (forgive the code, but the rationale is same)

```
public class SerialNumberValidatorFactory
{
    public static SerialNumberValidatorFactory newInstance(
           ProductCategory productCategory)
    {
        switch (productCategory)
        {
            case ProductCategory.Modem:
                return new ModemValidatorFactory();
            ....
        }
    }

    public abstract ISerialNumberValidator createValidator();
}

public class ModemValidatorFactory extends SerialNumberValidatorFactory
{
   public ISerialNumberValidator createValidator() 
   {
      return new ModemSerialNumberValidator("model", "number");
   }
}

ISerialNumberValidator = SerialNumberValidatorFactory.newInstance(productCategory).createValidator()
```